# Empty <li> tag after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This loop always gives me an empty `<li></li>` after creating the tags. Why is this? How can I fix it?

P.S. Loop goes 2 times (I checked).

```
function a(){
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $("#flist").append('<li id="file' + i '"<li/>');
        $("#flist").append('<li id="file' + i '_info"<li/>');
    }
}
```

HTML result:

```html
<ul id="flist" style="display: block;">
    <li id="file0">...</li>
    <li></li>
    <li id="file0_info"></li>
    <li></li>

    <li id="file1">...</li>
    <li></li>
    <li id="file1_info"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're missing a `>` on the opening `li` tag, and it should be `</li>`, not `<li/>`.

```
function a(){
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $("#flist").append('<li id="file' + i + '"></li>');
        $("#flist").append('<li id="file' + i + '_info"></li>');
    }
}
```

Also note that it would be quicker to generate a single HTML string and append to the DOM once:

```
function a() {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        html += '<li id="file' + i + '"></li><li id="file' + i + '_info"></li>';
    }
    $('#flist').append(html);
}
```

Comment: Efficient answer. :)

Comment: In your 2nd sample you missed '+' in concatenation twice (after 1st 'i' and after the 2nd).

Thank you for optimization. It really rocks!

I tested (with ChromeDevTools; with 4-time loop) unoptimized code, which took `3.95ms` to run, optimized - `1.79ms`, so it saves `2.16ms` with 2.2 times speedup.

Comment: So I did, updated, thanks. It's not a huge increase, but it all helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function a(){
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       $("#flist").append('<li id="file' + i '"></li>');
       $("#flist").append('<li id="file' + i '_info"></li>');
   }
}
```